# Moving folders in Terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal-server

I'm trying to move a folder into another folder in terminal, but when I enter this line:

```
mv South_America /North_America
```

South_America just completely disappears. It didn't move into the North_America folder? or go into my trash.

How do I move a folder?

Comment: `/North_America` may not be what you intended.

Comment: @muru I think that would be the answer link, not a duplicate.

Comment: There's small point that interests me: OP would receive message something like `mv: cannot move Sourth America to /North\ America: Permission denied`, if done without sudo, right ? and if he did is with sudo, then the `/North\ America` folder would be created , right ? I mean, i tested this with empty folder just now, same syntax as OP,  so, I guess OP's files are safe and sound in that `/North\ America` directory

Answer (score 5):

you are doing it wrong, you are trying to move a file inside `/` folder without `root` permissions

for you try getting your current directory by

```
pwd
```

and then try moving the files using

```
mv <folder to move> <destination>
```

try using relative locations ie:

```
mv /home/<user>/South_America /home/<user>/North_America/
```

for more information about the `mv` command type in the terminal

```
man mv
```

or

```
mv --help
```

Comment: When I entered mv South_America North_America it worked!

Answer (score 2):

`mv South_America /North_America` will move a folder called `South_America` on your current directory to a folder called `North_America` on your root folder (`/`).

To avoid this, you don't need to put a slash (`/`) before the second path.